# How to select inner objects within Mongoose documents with matching inner values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm somewhat new to Mongoose and not familiar with more complex queries, but essentially I'm trying to select all inner objects with two matching inner values.

I am trying to select all the inner message objects that have been reciprocated (sent and received to/from the same person). For instance, notice how the "to" and "from" values match:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("567f225438dh626f3f0d2767"),
    "messages" : {
        "sent": [
            { "to": "Bob", ... }
        ],
        "received": [
            { "from": "Bob", ... }
        ],
        ....
    },
    ....
}
```

Therefore, I expect to be returned the `{ "from": "Bob", ... }` inner object, as well as all other received messages that have a corresponding matching "sent to" value existing. How can I approach this kind of a query?

Comment: Can you show some sample documents and the expected output from those?

Comment: I was hoping that the above sample document would be sufficient for this simple example.

Comment: It may not be as simple as it looks for some people hence the recommendation to include some set of sample documents and the expected output in code to clarify things a little bit, that way you will get favourable responses. Just try it.

Comment: I was able to solve this by using a manual for-loop and extracting the common ones. I assume _underscore could also be used to filter the intersections.

Comment: You can answer your own question as well. I'm pretty sure there's another approach to this, most probably using the aggregation framework.

Answer (score 0):

My solution using a simple nested for-loop:

```
var received = user.messages.received || [],
    receivedCount = received.length,
    sent = user.messages.sent || [],
    sentCount = sent.length,
    results = [];

for (var r = 0; r < receivedCount; r++) {
    for (var s = 0; s < sentCount; s++) {
        if (sent[s] && sent[s].to &&
            received[s] && received[s].from &&
            sent[s].to === received[r].from) {
                results.push(received[s]);
        }
    }
}
```